# Assigning Integers to strings and then adding them

Tags: python, string, dictionary, integer

I'm trying to create a menu for a sandwich place as a mini project. I have most of what I need figured out, but I want to assign each menu item an integer for the price, and then add each number together for the final price.

```
 import pyinputplus as pyip


bread = ['White', 'Wheat', 'Sourdough'] #The Menu Options
protein = ['Chicken', 'Turkey', 'Ham', 'Tofu']
cheese = ['Cheddar', 'Swiss', 'Mozzarella']
sauce = ['Mayo', 'Mustard', 'Lettuce', 'Tomato']

OP1 = pyip.inputMenu(bread, prompt = 'What kind of bread? \n') #Asking for Bread
OP2 = pyip.inputMenu(protein, prompt = 'What kind of Protein? \n') #Asking for Protien
def OP3(): #Asking for Cheese and what kind they would like
    cyn = pyip.inputYesNo('Want any cheese? ')
    if cyn == 'yes':
        pyip.inputMenu(cheese, prompt = 'What kind of Cheese? \n')
def OP4(): #Asking for Sauce and what kind they would like
    syn = pyip.inputYesNo('Want any Sauce? ')
    if syn == 'yes':
        pyip.inputMenu(sauce, prompt = 'What kind of Sauce? \n')

OP3() #Calling the Cheese and Sauce Functions
OP4()

OP5 = pyip.inputNum(prompt='How Many Sandwiches would you Like? ') #Asking how many sandwiches they would like.

d = {'White': 3, 'Wheat': 1, 'Sourdough': 4, 'Chicken': 3, 'Turkey': 5, 'Ham': 3, 'Tofu': 9, 'Cheddar': 3, 'Swiss': 2, 'Mozzarella': 4, 'Mayo': 3, 'Mustard': 3, 'Lettuce': 3, 'Tomato': 90} #Dictionary I thought would convert the strings into numbers

print((OP1 + OP2 + OP3 + OP4) * OP5) #Final Price Equation
```

I tried making a dictionary so that the strings would be converted into integers that I could just add up later, but it gave me a type error "can only concatrenate str (not "function) to str

Does anyone know of a good way to assign an integer to a string based on user input so that way it can be added later?

Comment: You need to look up the value in the dictionary. `d[OP1] + d[OP2] ...`

Comment: `OP3` and `OP4` are functions, not variables, you have to call them with `()`. And then need to return something.

Comment: I was able to start off by printing OP1 + OP2, but when I tried multiplying the sum of those variables by OP5 using print(d[OP1]  + d[OP2] * d[OP5]) It would just throw a key error at me with the integer I entered for the OP5 Prompt

Comment: `OP5` is already a number, you don't need to look it up in the dictionary.

Comment: I was able to get it to work finally. Thanks for the help with the dictionary. As for the functions I just got rid of them and created new variables for the pyip.inputYesNo and nested OP3 and OP4 inside of an if statement detecting if the user input yes or no

Answer (score 0):

This part is inconsistent with the rest of your code and doesn't set OP3 nor OP4 to any price/ingredient

```
def OP3(): #Asking for Cheese and what kind they would like
    cyn = pyip.inputYesNo('Want any cheese? ')
    if cyn == 'yes':
        pyip.inputMenu(cheese, prompt = 'What kind of Cheese? \n')
def OP4(): #Asking for Sauce and what kind they would like
    syn = pyip.inputYesNo('Want any Sauce? ')
    if syn == 'yes':
        pyip.inputMenu(sauce, prompt = 'What kind of Sauce? \n')

OP3() #Calling the Cheese and Sauce Functions
OP4()
```

it should be

```
cyn = pyip.inputYesNo('Want any cheese? ')
if cyn == 'yes':
    OP3 = pyip.inputMenu(cheese, prompt = 'What kind of Cheese? \n')

syn = pyip.inputYesNo('Want any Sauce? ')
if syn == 'yes':
    OP4 = pyip.inputMenu(sauce, prompt = 'What kind of Sauce? \n')
```

at the end you need the prices from your dict, so you need to access the dict values with the keys you got from the Inputs and then print it.

```
price_option_1 = d[OP1]
price_option_2 = d[OP2]
if cyn == 'yes': 
    price_option_3 = d[OP3] 
else: 
    price_option_3 = 0
if syn == 'yes': 
    price_option_4 = d[OP4] 
else: 
    price_option_4 = 0
quantity = OP5
total_price = (price_option_1 + price_option_2 + price_option_3 + price_option_4) * quantity

print(total_price)
```

I was verbose to be clear, but you can use `p_OP1`, `p_OP2` or whatever in your variable naming.